# How to stop looping text animation

Tags: javascript, html

I am a student studying JavaScript.
I found the js code for the scrambled text animation, but I want to stop looping.
(Because I want to read the contents)
Anyone can explain to stop looping in the 'for or if' part?
Also, are there any unnecessary parts of the JavaScript code?
Thanks in advance for the answer.

html

```js
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————
// TextScramble
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————

class TextScramble {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el
    this.chars = 'かきくけこらりるれろ'
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ''
      const to = newText[i] || ''
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({
        from,
        to,
        start,
        end
      })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ''
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let {
        from,
        to,
        start,
        end,
        char
      } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
}

// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————
// Example
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————

const phrases = [
  'ロレム・イプサムの嘆き、トマト大好き学部のエリット、しかし時と活力、そのような労働と悲しみ、ブラインド行うにはいくつかの重要な事柄に座ります。長年にわたり、私は学区と長寿であれば、そのような刺激の取り組み、彼女のうち、運動の利点を分注を邪魔されたする人が来ます。クピダタットのつるの痛みになりたい宿題に、批判されてきたら痛み、マグナ逃亡しても結果の喜びを生成しません。先例クピダタットブラックは先例していない、つまり、彼らはあなたの悩みに責任がある人の、一般的な義務を捨て、魂を癒しています。'
]

const el = document.querySelector('.text')
const fx = new TextScramble(el)

let counter = 0
const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
    setTimeout(next, 800)
  })
  counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
}

next()
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="glitch" data-text="About">About</div>
    <div class="glow">About</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scanlines"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding delay in your loop
see if this helps you

```js
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) { 
   task(i); 
} 
  
function task(i) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
      // Add tasks to do 
  }, 2000 * i); 
}
```